# List widget not showing in app downloaded from testflight.But it is there when i run in iPhone Xr testing device

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight

In my flutter app List widget not showing in app downloaded from testflight. But it is there when I run in iPhone Xr testing device. this is the screen I get when I open the app from testflight build.
[image]

And the reality  There is a list widget that shows the data. When I test it in real testing device I get the exact data, But when I upload to testflight it not showing there.Please any body help me to find out the reason. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run your app in release config from xcode, check logs for any errors

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I changed runner scheme info to release , And I changed the signin to release . And archived again with Generic iOS device . But it not changed the app in testflight. Still the problem exist

Comment: No, I mean run from XCode using USB to see logs, don't archive